# finding least number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Question:  The least number which when divided by 5, 6 , 7 and 8 leaves a remainder 3, but when divided by 9 leaves no remainder, is:
>
> solution: L.C.M. of 5, 6, 7, 8 = 840. Required number is of the form 840k + 3.
>   Least value of k for which (840k + 3) is divisible by 9 is k = 2. Required number = (840 x 2 + 3) = 1683.

My Question is that how we came to know that value of k=2 ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want $280k+1$ to be divisible by $3$. Note that $279$ is divisible by $3$, so we want $k+1$ to be divisible by $3$. Not hard now!

If we do not initially divide by $3$, we can note that $840$ leaves remainder $3$ on division by $9$. so we want $3k+3$ to be divisible by $9$. The least positive $k$ that works is, by inspection, $2$.

Comment: thanks a lot. your explanation really helps me to find the value of k.

Comment: You are welcome.